# Solutions to traylabs/oracle-storage PHP web API Integration

Tags: php, oracle

There is a piece of code which keeps throwing this error:

```
RuntimeException: SplFileObject::__construct(86a03f5ac14227ae4e596750c3a90db1612f77ce1b00e4aa6cbd4b2dc5e69835.icturee.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/site/vendor/tray-labs/oracle-storage/src/Object/File.php:42 Stack trace: #0 /home/site/vendor/tray-labs/oracle-storage/src/Object/File.php(42): SplFileObject->__construct('86a03f5ac14227a...') #1 /home/site/vendor/tray-labs/oracle-storage/src/Service/UploadService.php(25): TrayLabs\OracleStorage\Object\File->getFile() #2 /home/site/vendor/tray-labs/oracle-storage/src/OracleStorage.php(64): TrayLabs\OracleStorage\Service\UploadService->handle('86a03f5ac14227a...', Object(TrayLabs\OracleStorage\Object\File)) #3 /home/site/includes/storageProcessor.php(15): TrayLabs\OracleStorage\OracleStorage->upload('86a03f5ac14227a...', Object(TrayLabs\OracleStorage\Object\File)) #4 /home/site/wwwroot/chumba.html(470): storeFile(Object(TrayLabs\OracleStorage\OracleStorage), '86a03f5ac14227a...', '86a03f5ac14227a...') #5 {main}
```

I have tried my best to follow the integration document of the traylabs\oracle-storage package like:

1. Add this line in composer.json file in the web app project's root folder

`require traylabs/oracle-storage`

2. Execute this command to install the package in the vendors directory

`php composer.phar update`

3. Create the configuration file `conf.php`

```
    return [ 'user'=>[
             'username'=>'example@gmail.com',
             'password'=>'#password'
            ], 'account'=>[
                'identifier'=>'bucket',
                'auth_url'=>'https://oraclecloud.com/object-storage/buckets/f4yay/items'
               ], 'storage'=>[
                'container'=>'items',
                'local_path'=>'/home/site/wwwroot/destination/',
                'cache'=>true
               ]         ];
```

4. creating the `processing.php` file for encapsulating  the file upload to cloud functionality as shown:

```
    <?php
    use \TrayLabs\OracleStorage\OracleStorage;
    use \TrayLabs\OracleStorage\Object\File;
    use \TrayLabs\OracleStorage\ExceptionFileNotFound;

    require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");

    function getClient() {
    $client=new OracleStorage(require '/home/site/includes/Conf.php');
    return $client;
    }
    //utility
    function storeFile($client,$filename) {
        $calledname=$client->upload("$filename", new File($filename));
        return $calledname;
    }
    ?>
```

5. include the `processing.php` file via `require_once()` function in several `products.html` files from which image files i.e jpeg/ping etc will be uploaded to the web app server and later to the oracle cloud object storage as shown here under:

```
    <?php
    use \TrayLabs\OracleStorage\OracleStorage;
    use \TrayLabs\OracleStorage\Object\File;
    use \TrayLabs\OracleStorage\ExceptionFileNotFound;

    require_once('./../includes/processing.php');
    require_once("./../vendor/autoload.php");

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
    {
        if ($_FILES['picha']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
            {                      
                $tmpName = $_FILES['picha']['tmp_name'];
                $name = basename($_FILES['picha']['name']);
                $ext = strtolower(substr($name, strripos($tmpName, '.')+1));
                $filename = hash_file('sha256', $tmpName) . '.' . $ext;

                $destination=__DIR__."/warehouse/$filename";
                $message=move_uploaded_file($tmpName,$destination);

                $filepath=$destination;
                $contents=fopen($filepath,'r');//getfilecontents($filepath);
                    try
                    {

                         $client=new getClient();
                         $itemname=storeFile($client,$filename);
                    }
                    catch(Exception $ex)
                    {
                         $ex->getMessage();
                         echo $ex;                 
                     }
                     unlink($destination);
                     //some more code goes here
            }

    }                
    ?>
```

For brevity I have removed some code such as html form elements and other associated data element for particular product

Comment: `86a03f5ac14227ae4e596750c3a90db1612f77ce1b00e4aa6cbd4b2dc5e69835.icturee.jpg` seems like a strange file name; are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Not so much so. As you can see in the final code section there is a stage where the uploaded file name is being hashed. Such names will be stored on database for later retreval on when a reference to particular product is made

Comment: I see - are you sure the directory is correct, though? Should you be using `storeFile(.., $destination)`?

Comment: I have used custom defined storeFile()  function so as to simplify code reuse. I could have several product types files. As some programming schools stresses that one should try to refactor the code, I thought that is nice idea rather than keep on calling the same stuff on each product file that could be written.

Comment: At the entry point that being /home/site/wwwroot/chumba.html where I call the function storeFile($client,$filename) I have included the processing.php fille in which storeFile() function is defined. About directory I  was thinking that the conf.php config file under the hood takes care of the local_path of the file store which is the destination folder in the web app server soon after the move_uploaded_file() function is called.

Comment: About directory I  was thinking that the conf.php config file under the hood takes care of the local_path of the file store which is the destination folder in the web app server soon after the move_uploaded_file() function is called. When I examine the folder path mentioned in the move_uploaded_file() function I can see all the multimedia files uploaded with their new hashed file names clearly just as the debug report showcases

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution. I remembered something that I should put on the checklist. I simply went to the kudu console for my app which is hosted in azure app service and changed the owner of folder where I kept the multimedia files to www-data and soon after that retest my app it is running smoothly as it supposed to do.